# How can we use GitHub Actions in Azure YML pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, github-actions

Is there any way to use GitHub Actions in Azure YML pipelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can not mix GitHub Actions and Azure YAML pipelines, since they are from two different platforms and have different syntaxes.

However, in Azure YAML pipelines, you can call the GitHub REST API "[**Create a workflow dispatch event**](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)" to trigger a GitHub Actions workflow run.

And in GitHub Actions workflow, you can use the "[**Azure Pipelines Action**](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-pipelines-action)" to trigger a pipeline.

Comment: GitHub API docs are now versioned, the updated link is https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event